# How to create a given size list of lists from a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary `a` which is

```
a = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5}
```

Now If I will give `size=2` than the output should be like a list of lists in which each list size should be equal to 2 , last list size doesn't matter, like in this case it should be like this

```
[[('a', 1), ('c', 3)], [('b', 2), ('e', 5)], [('d', 4)]]
```

or if `size = 3` than it should be like this `[[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)], [('e', 5), ('d', 4)]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all convert your dictionary into a list , which you can do easily like this

```
In [1]: a = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5}

In [2]: b = a.items()

In [3]: b
Out[3]: [('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('e', 5), ('d', 4)]
```

than use this method to make the chunks of the list for a given size

```
In [4]: def chunks(c, n):
   ...:     return [c[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(c), n)]
   ...: 

In [5]: list(chunks(b,2))
Out[5]: [[('a', 1), ('c', 3)], [('b', 2), ('e', 5)], [('d', 4)]]

In [6]: list(chunks(b,3))
Out[6]: [[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)], [('e', 5), ('d', 4)]]
```

Comment: In py3k, you'll need to construct a list from the iterable returned by `dict.items()`  (e.g. `b = list(a.items())`)

Comment: Or you could use itertools.islice directly on the iterable.